# Dynamically change state url page number for pagination in angualrjs

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angularjs-routing

how to change/add the state and url for pagination
example

```
.state('result.({pageNumber:[0-9]{1,4}})', {
            url: '/{pageNumber:[0-9]{1,4}}',
            templateUrl: 'tpl/search_result.html'
        })
```

in html

```
<a ui-sref="result.{{pageNumber}} ">{{ pageNumber }}</a>
```

Now the a html is added perfectly with **pageNumber** 
but in config.router.js I tried to increment the pageNumber. but I have no idea.

How to increment the pageNumber in state and URL

Answer (score 0):

you mentioned state in wrong way. please use like this

```
.state('result.pageNumber', {
    url: '/:pageNumber',
    templateUrl: 'tpl/search_result.html'
  });
```

Change to this. you pass like this

```
<a ui-sref="result.pageNumber({pageNumber : pageNumber})">{{ pageNumber }}</a>
```

Comment: And another one, I refreshed the page while I'm in another page like third page. url shows same but page showing first page result and first page link only in active state.